# Joomla Category Page Condition To Display A Module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template, theming

I want a link to a specific article on my site to appear on the page only if a specific category is in the view.

For eg: I have a category called FBrand. When someone is on the category page (viewing the category blog of that category), I wan't the article "List of FBrand Shops" on the page in a Custom HTML module in the form of an advertisement.

What I don't know is how to check the **condition of the category by the name or slug**, like in wordpress: `if( is_category( 'FBrand' ) ):` This is because the id of the category could be different in the production environment.

Comment: Which version of Joomla is this for? (1.0, 1.5 or 1.6/1.7)

Comment: I should've put that in the queston, my bad. It's 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this excellent extension:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/modules-management/3391

Metamod allows you to display modules based on all kinds of variables which should include the category slug. Check out http://www.metamodpro.com/jomgenius/parameters for all the options.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I've used it for other purposes but have found it to be extremely flexible.